# How to get cookies out of the android.webkit.CookieManager on a non io thread?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat, webviewclient

I have implemented the `shouldInterceptRequest` method on `WebViewClient`. In there I am using HttpURLConnection to load the resources myself. To do this I have to set the cookies on the url connection. This is all working perfectly fine on android 4.3 and below however on kitkat it freezes because there is a deadlock on the `CookieManager.getCookie(url)`. The issue is documented here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65786

Anyways I could read the cookie on a thread or something prior to the call to `shouldInterceptRequest` but I need the url that is passed on `shouldInterceptRequest` so I just don't know what to do. Is it possible to implement cookie saving in some other way for the WebView?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my reply on the bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65786#c8. I'm curious to see if that helps.